# request.url undefined type, why?

Tags: node.js, typescript, httpserver, definitelytyped

Why request.url is defined as optional within nodejs types?
If a Request come to the http server should have the url by definition.

Why there is a question mark here?
`url?: string;`

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/http.d.ts#L288

Comment: Did you read the comment right above it?

Comment: Yes, but if the request is not valid why an IncomingMessage exist?
(I'm pretty new to nodejs and I don't know the details)

Comment: the `url` is only valid for requests coming from `http.Server` presumably there are requests coming from elsewhere which implement `IncomingMessage` but do not require a `url`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about `http`/`Request` in node, but this seems to be the classic example of bad modeling (which is often found in the `@types/node` definitions, either due to how the types have been written or to the underlying design of the node.js API itself).

`IncomingMessage` is being modeled as a product type with optional keys instead of as a proper sum type - to distinguish the case of a client request from a server generated one. Comments about the invariants are then put above the single fields, making them useless in terms of TS / static type checking.

Reading just that definition, a better type def could have been:

```
interface ClientIncomingMessage extends stream.Readable {
  // ... many other fields ...
  url: string;
}

interface ServerIncomingMessage extends stream.Readable {
  // ... many other fields ...
  // no `url` fields here!
}

type IncomingMessage = ClientIncomingMessage | ServerIncomingMessage
```

Comment: I suggested these changes on [an open DefinitelyTyped ticket](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15808) but don't currently have time to implement them myself.  Soon, maybe?